# Django connect to IBM Cloud database

Tags: django, db2, django-migrations, django-database

I'm new in Django. I'm trying to connect Django app to IBM Cloud db, I loaded my data IBM cloud and created credionals.

Then installed ibm_db_django

```
$ easy_install ibm_db_django
```

Then in setting.py did import

```
import ibm_db_django
```

Then I added credionals in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE'   : 'ibm_db_django',
    'NAME'     : 'BLUDB',
    'USER'     : 'USER',
    'PASSWORD' : 'PASSWORD',
    'HOST'     : 'dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-lon02-02.services.eu-gb.bluemix.net',
    'PORT'     : '50000',
    'PROTOCOL' : 'TCPIP',
    'PCONNECT' :  True,
},
```

}

Otput of `python manage.py test django.contrib.auth` :

```
    System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

---

Is this enough to connect to ibm cloud db? 
Now how can I test is this connected to database, and how can I generate models from database?

Comment: You can test as described here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0060891.html It creates a sample project. What do you mean by "migrate tables"?

Comment: Hi, output of python --version:    Python 3.6.9 :: Anaconda, Inc.

Comment: python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())":     2.2.5

Comment: otput of `pip show ibm_db_django` :

`Name: ibm-db-django
Version: 1.2.0.0
Summary: DB2 support for Django framework.
Home-page: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ibm_db_django/
Author: Ambrish Bhargava, Tarun Pasrija, Rahul Priyadarshi
Author-email: opendev@us.ibm.com
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: c:\users\internet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_django-1.2.0.0-py3.6.egg
Requires: ibm-db, django
Required-by: `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the versions below, I can connect python + django + ibm_db_django + Db2-on-cloud .

Running `python manage.py migrate` shows that the connection to Db2-on-cloud is succeeding.

Depending on versions, the `python manage.py migrate` might fail with the Db2-on-cloud 'lite' (free) plan, if specific database permissions are missing.

To work further with django after running the `manage.py migrate` successfully, please follow the online tutorial for your version of django at `djangoproject.com` .

I tried these versions (february 2020):

```
python          3.6.9  x64
pip             20.0.2
django          2.2.5
ibm_db          3.0.1
ibm_db_django   1.2.0.0a0  (lower versions always failed).
```

**Note**: other combinations might work, your mileage may vary.

I patched the `ibm_db_dbi.py` to workaround an open defect as detailed on github
(https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb-django/issues/44)
 (thanks to trebor74hr )

To get the `manage.py migrate` step working, the three `settings.py` changes I made were:

(1) The installed apps may vary with your versions and your app.

```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'django.contrib.redirects',
    'django.contrib.sites',

]
```

(2)

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
  'ENGINE'   : 'ibm_db_django',
  'NAME'     : 'bludb',
  'USER'     : '......',
  'PASSWORD' : '...............',
  'HOST'     : 'dashdb-txn-sbox-............services....bluemix.net',
  'PORT'     : '50000',
  'PCONNECT' :  True,      #Optional property. It is true by default
  }
}
```

(3)

```
#USE_TZ = True
   (or remove the line, the # makes it a comment ).
```